# com dll written in C

Tags: c, regsvr32

I make a dll on c and I was trying to register it with regsvr32 but it shows the error: the module was loaded but the entry-point was not found, so I was searching the error and find that only com dll can be register using regsvr32, so my question is: Is it possible to write a com dll in C and register it using regsvr32?

Comment: If you don't know about COM, you don't need regsvr32 at all.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C

Comment: Hi @SLaks, this is my problem, one client of the company I work has problem with a dll written in VB, so my team prefered to make a dll written in c to improve performance and to replace that dll, so the steps that the client take are that first the client register the dll using regsvr32 and later call it from one program that the client have, so when the client try to register this new dll written on c it show the error mentioned

Comment: Which version of VB? You need to emulate the exact interface, which means you need to learn COM or .Net.

Comment: It is not impossible, the Geneva Convention on Programmers' Rights is merely a guideline.  Just don't tell anybody about it, especially SO users.

Comment: thanks to all, we are going to make a VB program instead of using C, I think that it would be more easy to make a com dll with VB, if you have any suggestion please advise me

Comment: "prefered to make a dll written in c to improve performance" ... there is not such guarantee. "has problem with a dll written in VB" in pure C I guess only more problems